Рисование фигур в окне Avalonia по команде пользователя
Передо мной стоит задача отрисовывать некоторые фигуры (прямоугольники, линии и т. д.) в окне, созданном на Avalonia по команде пользователя (например, по нажатию кнопки). Я переопределил метод Render у MainView, наследуемого от UserControl.
Но остается непонятным, как сделать отрисовку фигур по команде пользователя (а не один раз при запуске приложения, как это сделано сейчас)?
public partial class MainView : UserControl
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    public sealed override void Render(DrawingContext context)
    {
        var p1 = new Point(20, 20);
        var p2 = new Point(300, 300);
        var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 20, lineCap: PenLineCap.Square);
        context.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
    }
}


https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/reference/controls/canvas

Конкретизируйте задачу. Пользователь нажимает кнопку (мыши? на экране?) и рисуются сразу все фигуры? или одна фигура за раз? в заданном заранее месте рисуются, или где курсор пользователя? прежде всего задачу нужно нормально сформулировать, а потом уже думать, какими средствами её сделать.
